# Laravel can't find a provider from module

Tags: php, laravel, provider

When I try to start even tinker, I see:

```
Class 'Modules\BookingSystem\Providers\BookingSystemServiceProvider' not found
```

But the class is in the specified place. I try to dump autoload with composer but still I get:

```
> @php artisan package:discover

In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

Class 'Modules\BookingSystem\Providers\BookingSystemServiceProvider'
not found


Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event 
returned with error code 1
```

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: have you try composer install?

Comment: is it your own class? have you set the autoload config in the composer.json?

Comment: Do note that the top line is the _namespace_, and not the _path_ of the file.

Comment: `composer dump` might help.

Comment: guys could you elaborate what I need to do with this autoload config in composer.json?

Answer (score 0):

Given the facts that are present in the question, this seems the most likely solution:

in `composer.json` chance

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"

    }
},
```

to

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Modules\\": "modules/"
    }
},
```

then run `composer dump` once :)